# "Flat links" with Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to convert URLs with GET variables from something like

```
http://domain.com/?username=john
```

to

```
http://domain.com/john
```

using following the articles [here](http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/) and [here](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php#section-not_so_simple).

Using the example in the first article (with a slight modification) - `RewriteRule .* index.php` - I have gotten that to work. The first problem is, I still want to be able to access the other files in the same directory. So the closest I've gotten so far is `RewriteRule index\.php/(.+) index.php?username=$1`, which is still not ideal because I don't want the filename in the URL, but there's another problem. index.php is set as the DirectoryIndex, and I have no idea how to match that.

I'm still very much a beginner at configuring Apache, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \buser=\w+
RewriteRule .* user.php [L]
```

put instead of user.php the name of your script.